# Jquery input update (with remaining characters) for more than one input copy

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I've got a little problem about updating text field (characters count).
Here is the code

```
function updateCountdowt() {
            var remainingt = 30 - jQuery('.account-edit-field').val().length;
            jQuery('.input-text-count').text(remainingt);
}

$(document).ready(function(){   
        updateCountdowt();
        $('input.account-edit-field').on('keyup', function() {
            updateCountdowt();
        });
        $('input.account-edit-field').on('change', function() {
            updateCountdowt();
        });
});
```

The main problem is that I have more than one input with class ".account-edit-field". And here is strange thing begins, if I will edit first input - everything works fine. If I will left some text in first input - all the others will show remaining characters from the first input and will not show remaining characters in current input (other than first). How could I change the code to work it only for current input, not for every input on the page? Here is the HTML structure:

```
<div class="account-edit-group">    
                    <input type="text" value="" class="account-edit-field">
                    <span class="input-text-count"></span>
                    <div>
                        <button class="account-edit-field-save"> </button><button class="account-edit-field-cancel"> </button>
                    </div>                                  
                    <div class="account-edit-field-warning"><span class="w-text"></span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USe like this

```
     $('input.account-edit-field').on('keyup', function() {
        $(this).next('.input-text-count').text(30-$(this).val().length);
    });
    $('input.account-edit-field').on('change', function() {
         $(this).next('.input-text-count').text(30-$(this).val().length);
    });
```

If you want to restring the input with length, you can use `maxlength` property in your input field

```
<input type="text" value="" maxlength="30" class="account-edit-field">
```

Comment: Works fine, thank you (I will accept your answer in 7 minutes).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is updateCountdown doesn't know which input field you are referring to. Just update the values inside the .on() functions and use $(this) to refer to current elements.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="account-edit-group">    
                    <input type="text" class="account-edit-field">
                    <span class="input-text-count">30</span>
                    <input type="text" class="account-edit-field">
                    <span class="input-text-count">30</span>
                    <input type="text" class="account-edit-field">
                    <span class="input-text-count">30</span>                                                        
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
        $('.account-edit-group').on('keyup', "input", function() {
            var remaining = 30 - $(this).val().length;
            $(this).next().text(remaining);
        });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RBFJy/1/)**